# What's up with vDSP?

Tags: signal-processing, accelerate-framework, vdsp

In trying to use functions like zrvmul, vvsinf, and vvcosf (defined in vForce.h) I get "no matching function" errors. I am #including the accelerate framework, and have it linked in build phases. Moreover, I'm using other accelerate functions like vDSP_fft_zip with no trouble.

I can work around the problem using for loops, of course. But can anybody illuminate the situation for me? Is there a way to still use the vForce functions? If so how?

Comment: Please edit your question and add (a) an actual compile-able example, (b) the exact compile or link command that is failing, and (c) the exact error message(s) produced.  Without that information, any answers are wild guesses at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

My problem was that I passed some incorrect parameters to the functions - I needed to be more careful with pointers.

The error message was cryptic, and the issue of legacy macros was a red herring.

Comment: Yes, you're exactly right. I wasn't used to objective-C error messages in Xcode at the time. The parameters' types are part of the function definition, so wrong types in the call will result in a "function not found" type of error.